# PHP code don't work perfectly online host but works on local host

Tags: php, mysql, forms, function, search

My PHP code perfectly works on localhost, It gives exact output.
When I try to make it online, the search filter won't work and it gives output as without filter.

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE Name LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);

}
 else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM product";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mall");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}

?>
```

Comment: Which error is getting? Have you enabled error reporting?

Comment: You should post the full error in order to get a better understanding of the problem. Just the code isn't enough. 
The problem may rely on this line     $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mall");
because, online, this connection is not valid, you should put your db connection that the online server should use and not your local connection

Comment: Sorry man you're right, I didn't post the full error and thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the configuration for your online database:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("DOMAIN", "LIVE_MYSQL_USER", "LIVE_MYSQL_PASSWORD", "mall");
```

Comment: That is a good guess, but without the clear error description we can't know for sure that this was the issue. Shouldn't this be a comment instead?

Comment: Thank you for answering and sorry to belated.